# Bash clear screen except first line

Tags: bash

My script echoes some text and does further processing.
Using tput i want to clear screen maintaining first line on screen.

Eg.

```
echo Started
seq 1000
tput cup 1 0 && tput ed
```

So that Started remains on screen and everhthing else is cleared
But it works only when output is smaller like seq 10, but not with longer scrolled output

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just pipe the output to a pager like `less` or `more`?

Answer (score 4):

Some terminals let you define a scrolling region:

```
tput csr 1 "$(( ${LINES:-$(tput lines)} - 1 ))"
tput clear
echo Started
seq 1000
```

To set the scrolling region from second to last line so the "Started" line is not scrolled off the screen. And then:

```
tput cup 1 0 && tput ed
```

again to clear from the second to last line.

See terminfo(5) for details.

Since version 608, `less` also has a `--header=lines[,cols]` option which allows specifying header lines that are not scrolled:

```
{
  echo Started; seq 1000
} | less --header=1
```

You can add the `-X` option for the output including header to stay on screen after `less` has returned. See also the `-R` option for `less` to let through the graphic rendition escape sequences and `-F` for it not to paginate if the input fits on the screen.